# Deactivate guard called twice when manually changing route or pressing back/forward

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using angular 2.0 stable version and want to ask users to confirm before leaving a page (their changes won't be saved).

The issue is that the "CanDeactivate" guard implemented is called twice if the user wishes to visit a lazy loaded page. (using hash location strategy)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download and setup https://github.com/iurii-kyrylenko/angular2-webpack
2. Setup CanDeactivate guard

*app.routing.ts*

```
{ path: 'task1', component: Task1Component, canDeactivate: ['candeactivate'] },
```

*app/task-1/task1.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [Task1Component],
    exports: [Task1Component],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: 'candeactivate',
            useValue: () => {
                console.log("can deactivate");
                return confirm("Test");
            }
        }
    ]
})
export class Task1Module {}
```

3. Start on "localhost:8080/#/task1"
4. Manually change url to "localhost:8080/#/task2"

Notice that you are asked twice to confirm. I found https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11754 but it doesn't have any solution for now.

Is there any workaround for it ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @skgyan No. I ended up saving the value from the first confirmation in a cookie with 1 sec expiration and skip the second confirmation if the cookie is not empty.

Comment: for me, canActivate is causing this issue. I used Observable approach to solve this.
Took help from here - https://medium.com/@OlegVaraksin/displaying-primeng-confirmation-dialog-with-guarded-routes-f5d07e646b4a#.3pmpkgxbu